# Poisson's equation with no explicit position dependence

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

Are there any ways for finding analytic general solutions for Poisson's equation of the form
$$
\nabla^{2}\phi=f(\phi)
$$
in two or three dimensions, where $f$ is some arbitrary (integrable) function? I can't see how to use any of the techniques for solving Laplace's equation.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You probably need a little more than just integrability for $f$ to obtain solutions. You also need boundary conditions.

Comment: This could be converted to an integral equation $$\phi(\vec r) =\int_V f(\phi(\vec r')) G(\vec r|\vec r')dV'$$The integral equation might facilitate numerical solutions.